# Keeping crawfish alive overnight?

Tags: crawfish

I'm going to buy Crawfish this Friday night at 9 or 10 and boil them Saturday at noon. Is it possible to keep Crawfish alive overnight? If possible how does one do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh you're fine. For maximum freshness, follow the advice from (this one is better, no spurious exclamation points!)  [this online FAQ](http://crawfishshack.com/qanda.htm)

> How do I keep crawfish alive until I boil them?
>
> Keep them in the sack and cool with ice, but not submerged in water. A large ice chest works great with the drain spout open and the lid cracked for breathing. Properly wash the crawfish by submerging 2-3 times in clean water. Let them soak for 20-30 minutes the last time. Use of salt on final cleaning is best.

Comment: I'm not contradicting because I don't know, but I'd be wary of information that uses so many exclamation marks ...

Comment: How uncanny i was about to buy from this company. Too bad they are out.

Comment: @setek I think the information is probably reliable and correct, but I sure understand what you mean about the excess exclamation marks.

Comment: Yes, there is that. I'll look for a better one! :)

Comment: [link](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/crawfish-boil-recipe.html#) From the master himself.  I seem to recall him saying on that episode that you can leave them in water overnight, changing it occasionally, to 'flush' the digestive tract.  Don't quote me on that though...